# how to load a module within python debugger

Tags: python, debugging

This looks like something simple but I could not find the answer so far -

I have just learnt python and need to start learning pdb. In my module I have the usual `if __name__ == __main_` trick to execute some code when the module is run as a program.

So far I have been running it via `python -m mymod arg1 arg2` syntax

Now I want to do exactly the same thing from inside pdb. Normally in C, I would just do `gdb mybinary` followed by `run arg1 arg2`

But I cannot figure out how to achieve the same thing in pdb.

I am sure there has to be a simple way to achieve this but it is taking me too long to search for it..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
python -m pdb mymod.py arg1 arg2
```

That should start up pdb debugging mymod.py (if mymod.py is not in the current directory then you'll have to specify the path).

Alternatively set a breakpoint in your code where you want to start debugging. The usual way to get a breakpoint into pdb is:

```
if somecondition:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

You can make the condition whatever is convenient to ensure the breakpoint doesn't trigger too soon.

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion worked fine. The first one cannot load multiple modules using -m , I will figure out the syntax for that one later. For now, will just use the second way.